# How to Transpose multiple columns into multiple rows but retain primary keys as is using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe which can be generated from the code given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'date1': ['12/31/2007','11/25/2009','10/06/2005'],'date1derived':[0,0,0],'val1':[2,4,6],'date2': ['12/31/2017','11/25/2019','10/06/2015'],'date2derived':[0,0,0],'val2':[1,3,5],'date3':['12/31/2027','11/25/2029','10/06/2025'],'date3derived':[0,0,0],'val3':[7,9,11]})
```

The dataframe looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to retain the rows of each person as seperate rows and not as columns like shown in screenshot above.In addition, I want the date1derived,date2derived columns to be dropped.

I did try below approaches but they didn't provide the expected output

```
1) df.set_index(['person_id']).stack()/unstack
2) df.set_index(['person_id','date1','date2','date3']).stack()/unstack()
3) df.set_index('person_id').unstack()/stack
```

How can I get an output to be like this? I have more than 600 columns, so I don't think writing the column names manually would help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) problem:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['date', 'val'], i='person_id', j='grp').sort_index(level=0)
```

---

```
                     date  val
person_id grp                 
1         1    12/31/2007    2
          2    12/31/2017    1
          3    12/31/2027    7
2         1    11/25/2009    4
          2    11/25/2019    3
          3    11/25/2029    9
3         1    10/06/2005    6
          2    10/06/2015    5
          3    10/06/2025   11
```

---

To match your expected output:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['date', 'val'], i='person_id', j='grp').sort_index(level=0)
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

---

```
   person_id        date  val
0          1  12/31/2007    2
1          1  12/31/2017    1
2          1  12/31/2027    7
3          2  11/25/2009    4
4          2  11/25/2019    3
5          2  11/25/2029    9
6          3  10/06/2005    6
7          3  10/06/2015    5
8          3  10/06/2025   11
```

Comment: Hi Erfan. When I apply this on my real dataset with more than 200 columns, I get empty dataframe. can you please help me know what can be the issue? Column names are right

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without **wide_to_long()** but just with **append()**

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, 4):
    new_df = df[['person_id', f'date{i}', f'val{i}']]
    new_df.columns = ['person_id', 'date', 'val']
    df2 = df2.append(new_df)
df2.sort_values('person_id').reset_index(drop=True)
```

ouput :

```py
   person_id        date  val
0          1  12/31/2007    2
1          1  12/31/2017    1
2          1  12/31/2027    7
3          2  11/25/2009    4
4          2  11/25/2019    3
5          2  11/25/2029    9
6          3  10/06/2005    6
7          3  10/06/2015    5
8          3  10/06/2025   11
```

Comment: I don't know why but in my real data, when I apply this, it gives NA for few valid records

Comment: @AVLES. Try with 
**df2 = df2.append(new_df, ignore_index=True, sort=False)**
If this not work I can't see where the issue come from.